# SQLite seems to have a problem with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

I have a problem with the SQLite in-memory database. The normal database is working.

This is my model code

```cs
    public class Log
    {   
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

The SQL statement to create the table

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditLogs]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT newid() PRIMARY KEY,
    [Message] varchar(max) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (ISJSON([Message])> 0),
    [CreatedAt] datetime NOT NULL default GetDate()
)
```

The error

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: AuditLogs.CreatedAt'.
```

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
```

The problem with the Entity Framework is that it won't generate keys for you. If it is database-generated then some trigger in the database would still need to create this ID. This is generally done when the ID is of type `int`, but not `Guid`. Then again, SQLite is a weird database provider to begin with as it doesn't really has datatypes. Data type definitions are more suggestions and not enforced by the engine. (But EF will enforce it.)
Anyways, since you use Guids there's nothing wrong with assigning new values to the property, as they will be overwritten by the value in the database on retrieval. But SQLite isn't really generating values for you.
Also, I would use `public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now();` for the same reason. I myself actually had similar problems but I use the Fluid API instead and use this:

```
    var hostBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Host>();
    hostBuilder
        .Property(r => r.Id)
        .HasColumnOrder(0)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("Key")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(36)")
        .HasComment($"Primary key");
    hostBuilder
        .Property<DateTime>("Created")
        .HasColumnOrder(1)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasComment($"When was it created?");
    hostBuilder
        .HasKey(r => r.Id)
        .HasName($"PK_Visitor_Host_Key");
```

And my class only has the `Id` property defined, as I don't need the Created field in my project. It still gets added, though! The `HasDefaultValueSql()` call will tell that the field is database-generated, including how it's generated. You might want to look into this [Fluid API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties) for your project. I prefer it over those attributes as it provides more options and better control, plus I can add fields to tables that are not important for my code, yet still required for other purposes...
(Btw. You don't want timestamps to be unique as two records could be created at exactly the same timestamp on fast systems.)

Comment: With a real database, I have no problem. The solution seems to look for an alternative in-memory database provider because the testing code should not change the production code.